# FreeRadius 30.5 - Package fails to install - error 10 (files named incorrectly)

Tags: software-installation, compiling, make

Super noob here. I'm probably trying to chew more than I can swallow.
I only started using Ubuntu a week ago

I'm running the latest Ubuntu 14, with BIND9 (tutorials helped setup the DNS), and I've been fighting with FreeRadius 2.X and now 3.X.

Primarily I've been following [a guide](http://cubicspot.blogspot.com/2013/04/setting-up-wpa2-enterprise-aes-with.html) I found...

The repositories only have 2.1.12 but I downloaded the 3.0.5 GZ package from their site.

Messed around with 2.1.12 too much, long story short... it won't reinstall properly (files, directories missing...PITA)

So 3.0.5, I tried installing, after decompressing it, and both MAKE and CHECKINSTALL fail. Google failed to pinpoint why renaming the "MAKE.INC.IN" to "MAKE.INC" still halts the install. There are several files scattered throughout the directory that end in "IN" so I figured that has something to do with the compressed origin of the package.
Also, gEDIT confirmed the MAKEFILE is calling make.inc. I'm at a loss as to why I can't get the package installed. The install instructions provided by the developer say to use `./configure`, `make`, and `make install` too.

Below is the output of my make install and make, both output the same "error 10"

```
leonardo@consiglieri-DNS:~/Desktop/freeradius-server-3.0.5$ sudo make install
Makefile:10: *** Missing 'Make.inc' Run './configure [options]' and retry.  Stop.
```

CHECKINSTALL, If I manually rename from make.inc.in to make.inc:

```
Installing with make install...

========================= Installation results ===========================
scripts/boiler.mk:623: @abs_top_builddir@/main.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `@abs_top_builddir@/main.mk'.  Stop.

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Cleaning up...OK

Bye.

leonardo@consiglieri-DNS:~/Desktop/freeradius-server-3.0.5$
```

List of files...

```
leonardo@consiglieri-DNS:~/Desktop/freeradius-server-3.0.5$ ls -a
.             autogen.sh    configure     debian          INSTALL.rst  main.mk      mibs        redhat   suse
..            config.guess  configure.ac  doc             install-sh   Makefile     missing     scripts  .travis.yml
acinclude.m4  config.log    COPYRIGHT     .gitattributes  LICENSE      Make.inc.in  raddb       share    VERSION
aclocal.m4    config.sub    CREDITS       .gitignore      m4           man          README.rst  src
```

Below is the output of my `./configure`:

```
leonardo@consiglieri-DNS:~/Desktop/freeradius-server-3.0.5$ sudo ./configure
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking whether we are using SUNPro C... no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking if compiler is clang... no
checking for the compiler flag "-Qunused-arguments"... no
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... 64
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for gmake... no
checking for make... /usr/bin/make
checking number of system cores... 2
checking for git... no
checking docdir... ${datadir}/doc/freeradius
checking logdir... ${localstatedir}/log/radius
checking radacctdir... ${logdir}/radacct
checking raddbdir... ${sysconfdir}/raddb
checking dictdir... ${datarootdir}/freeradius
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for snmpget... no
configure: WARNING: snmpget not found - Simultaneous-Use and checkrad may not work
checking for snmpwalk... no
configure: WARNING: snmpwalk not found - Simultaneous-Use and checkrad may not work
checking for rusers... /usr/bin/rusers
checking for locate... /usr/bin/locate
checking for dirname... /usr/bin/dirname
checking for grep... (cached) /bin/grep
checking for _talloc in -ltalloc... no
checking for _talloc in -ltalloc in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu... no
checking for _talloc in -ltalloc in /usr/share/doc... no
checking for _talloc in -ltalloc in /usr/share/doc/libtalloc2... no
checking for _talloc in -ltalloc in /var/lib/dpkg/info... no
checking for _talloc in -ltalloc in /usr/local/lib... no
checking for _talloc in -ltalloc in /opt/lib... no
configure: WARNING: talloc library not found. Use --with-talloc-lib-dir=<path>.
configure: error: FreeRADIUS requires libtalloc
leonardo@consiglieri-DNS:~/Desktop/freeradius-server-3.0.5$
```

Answer (score 5):

You haven't completed configuration properly, before running `make`:

```
Makefile:10: *** Missing 'Make.inc' Run './configure [options]' and retry.  Stop.
```

And configure has been interrupted because of that:

```
configure: WARNING: talloc library not found. Use --with-talloc-lib-dir=<path>.
configure: error: FreeRADIUS requires libtalloc
```

That's a "disadvantage" of building your own binaries from sources - you have to check what's needed, review some compilation options to get features you may need.
Also read output in case there are some errors.

Deb packages would be easier way - at a cost of a bit older version.

Anyway - for now you need `libtalloc`. It may happen, however, that you will need something more yet - you'll see when trying to configure and compile again.

Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like I had this issue too, but solved it by installing `libtalloc-dev`.

```
sudo apt-get install libtalloc-dev
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yup!!! it's worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I create a directory called freeradius at
`/etc/freeradius`:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/freeradius
```

then I used these commands:

```
wget https://www.samba.org/ftp/talloc/talloc-2.1.0.tar.gz
tar zxvf talloc-2.1.0.tar.gz
cd talloc-2.1.0
./configure --without-gettext
make
make install
wget ftp://ftp.freeradius.org/pub/freeradius/freeradius-server-3.0.12.tar.gz
tar -zxvf freeradius-server-3.0.12.tar.gz
cd freeradius-server-3.0.12
./configure --prefix=/etc/freeradius
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Thanks to all guys for the support and help!

Answer (score 0):

We can use this (`curl` must be installed):

```
curl -LOk https://www.samba.org/ftp/talloc/talloc-2.1.0.tar.gz
tar zxvf talloc-2.1.0.tar.gz
cd talloc-2.1.0
./configure --without-gettext
make
sudo make install
```